# Align div at the bottom of bootstrap col

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I align div element at the bottom of parent element while using bootstrap col?

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.bottom {
  position: relative;
}

.bottom-div {
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-3 bottom">
    <div class="bottom-div"> TEST1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    TEST2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    TEST3
  </div>
</div>
```

bottom `div` element does not align at bottom. What is correct way of doing this? Thanks.

UPDATE: `Div` element runs out of wrapper (it basically moves up)

Comment: You should make the column relative, if you want that to be the reference point for the absolute positioning. The more modern approach would be to use flexbox.

Comment: @CBroe I updated based on your suggestion. Still confused.

Comment: Create a [mcve], please.

Comment: @CBroe http://www.bootply.com/QADpVrll1M

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you're trying to do, as @CBroe said flexbox would be the best way but try this:-

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
.wrapper{
    background-color:green;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
   
}
  
.bottom-div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.testclass {
     height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-3 testclass">
    <div class="bottom-div">  TEST1 </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
     TEST2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
     TEST3
  </div>
</div>
```